# Issue in Bullet and Arrow navigator in JSSOR grid slider

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, slider, jssor

I have dynamically created a JSSOR grid slider.

```js
//GridSlider.js
slider1_container_clicked = function (rowIndex, rowItem)
{
 alert("You have clicked slide : " +  (rowItem + 1) + " on row : " + (rowIndex + 1)  );
}
function CreateGridSlider (_name, _container)
{
 var jssor_grid_slider;  
 //var jssor_row_slider;
 this.nestedSliders = [];
 this.nestedSliderObjects = [];
 this.currentRowItem;
 this.isSlideClicked=false;
 
 function BulletNavigatorStyle ()
  {   
   try
   {
    var bulletcss = '.jssorb03 div, .jssorb03 div:hover, .jssorb03 .av { background: url(images/b05.png) no-repeat; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;} .jssorb03 div { background-position: -5px -4px; } .jssorb03 div:hover, .jssorb03 .av:hover { background-position: -35px -4px; } .jssorb03 .av { background-position: -65px -4px; }.jssorb03 .dn, .jssorb03 .dn:hover { background-position: -95px -4px; }'
    
    bulletstyle = document.createElement('style');
    bulletstyle.type = 'text/css';
    if (bulletstyle.styleSheet)
    {
     bulletstyle.styleSheet.cssText = bulletcss;
    } else 
    {
     bulletstyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(bulletcss));
    }
    //_container.appendChild(bulletstyle);
    
    return bulletstyle;
   }
   catch(e)
   {
    alert("Error :: SliderOptions() :: BulletNavigatorStyle() :: " + e.Message);
   }
  };
  
  GridBulletNavigatorStyle = function()
  {   
   try
   {
    var bulletcss = '.jssorb02 div, .jssorb02 div:hover, .jssorb02 .av { background: url(images/b02.png) no-repeat; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;} .jssorb02 div { background-position: -5px -5px; } .jssorb02 div:hover, .jssorb02 .av:hover { background-position: -35px -5px; } .jssorb02 .av { background-position: -65px -5px; }.jssorb02 .dn, .jssorb02 .dn:hover { background-position: -95px -5px; }'
    
    bulletstyle = document.createElement('style');
    bulletstyle.type = 'text/css';
    if (bulletstyle.styleSheet)
    {
     bulletstyle.styleSheet.cssText = bulletcss;
    } else 
    {
     bulletstyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(bulletcss));
    }
    //_container.appendChild(bulletstyle);
    
    return bulletstyle;
   }
   catch(e)
   {
    alert("Error :: SliderOptions() :: GridBulletNavigatorStyle() :: " + e.Message);
    alert("Error :: SliderOptions() :: GridBulletNavigatorStyle() :: " + e.Message);
   }
  };
 
  BulletNavigator = function()
  { 
   try
   {
    var divBulletNav = document.createElement("div");        
    divBulletNav.setAttribute("u","navigator");
    divBulletNav.setAttribute("class","jssorb03");
    divBulletNav.setAttribute("style","position: absolute; bottom: 10px; left: 6px;");
    //_container.appendChild(divBulletNav);
    
    var divTemplate = document.createElement("div");        
    divTemplate.setAttribute("u","prototype");    
    divTemplate.setAttribute("style","position: absolute; width: 21px; height: 21px; text-align:center; line-height:21px; color:white; font-size:12px;");
        
     
     
    divBulletNav.appendChild(divTemplate);
    return divBulletNav;
   }
   catch(e)
   {
    alert("Error :: SliderOptions() :: BulletNavigator() :: " + e.Message);
   }
  };
  
  GridBulletNavigator = function()
  { 
   try
   {
    var divBulletNav = document.createElement("div");        
    divBulletNav.setAttribute("u","navigator");
    divBulletNav.setAttribute("class","jssorb02");
    divBulletNav.setAttribute("style","position: absolute; bottom: 50px; left: 6px;");
    //_container.appendChild(divBulletNav);
    
    var divTemplate = document.createElement("div");        
    divTemplate.setAttribute("u","prototype");    
    divTemplate.setAttribute("style","position: absolute; width: 21px; height: 21px; text-align:center; line-height:21px; color:white; font-size:12px;");
        
    var divNumberTemplate = document.createElement("div");        
    divNumberTemplate.setAttribute("u","numbertemplate");        
    divTemplate.appendChild(divNumberTemplate);
    
    divBulletNav.appendChild(divTemplate);
    return divBulletNav;
   }
   catch(e)
   {
    alert("Error :: SliderOptions() :: BulletNavigator() :: " + e.Message);
   }
  };
 
  HorizontalArrowNavigatorStyle = function()
  { 
   try
   {
    arrowcss = '.jssora03l, .jssora03r, .jssora03ldn, .jssora03rdn {position: absolute;cursor: pointer;display: block;background: url(images/a03.png) no-repeat;overflow: hidden;} .jssora03l {background-position: -3px -33px;} .jssora03r { background-position: -63px -33px; } .jssora03l:hover { background-position: -123px -33px; } .jssora03r:hover { background-position: -183px -33px; } .jssora03ldn { background-position: -243px -33px; } .jssora03rdn { background-position: -303px -33px; }'
    
    arrowstyle = document.createElement('style');
    arrowstyle.type = 'text/css';
    if (arrowstyle.styleSheet){
     arrowstyle.styleSheet.cssText = arrowcss;
    } else {
     arrowstyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arrowcss));
    }
    //_container.appendChild(arrowstyle);
    
    return arrowstyle;
   }
   catch(e)
   {
    alert("Error :: SliderOptions() :: ArrowNavigatorHorizontalStyle() :: " + e.Message);
   }
  };
  
  HorizontalArrowNavigatorPrevious = function()
  {
   try
   {
    divLeftArrowNav = document.createElement("span");        
    divLeftArrowNav.setAttribute("u","arrowleft");
    divLeftArrowNav.setAttribute("class","jssora03l");
    divLeftArrowNav.setAttribute("style","width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 40%; left: 8px;");
    //_container.appendChild(divLeftArrowNav);
    
    return divLeftArrowNav;
   }
   catch(e)
   {
    alert("Error :: SliderOptions() :: LeftArrowNavigatorHorizontal() :: " + e.Message);
   }
  };
  
  HorizontalArrowNavigatorNext = function()
  { 
   try
   {
    divRightArrowNav = document.createElement("span");        
    divRightArrowNav.setAttribute("u","arrowright");
    divRightArrowNav.setAttribute("class","jssora03r");
    divRightArrowNav.setAttribute("style","width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 40%; right: 8px");
    //_container.appendChild(divRightArrowNav); 

    return divRightArrowNav;   
   }
   catch(e)
   {
    alert("Error :: SliderOptions() :: RightArrowNavigatorHorizontal() :: " + e.Message);
   }
  };
  
  VerticalArrowNavigatorStyle = function()
  { 
   try
   {
    arrowcss = '.jssora03u, .jssora03d, .jssora03udn, .jssora03ddn {position: absolute;cursor: pointer;display: block;background: url(images/a08.png) no-repeat;overflow: hidden; opacity: .4; filter:alpha(opacity=40);} .jssora03u { background-position: -5px -35px;}.jssora03d {background-position: -65px -35px;}.jssora03u:hover {background-position: -5px -35px;opacity: .8; filter:alpha(opacity=80);} .jssora03d:hover {background-position: -65px -35px;opacity: .8; filter:alpha(opacity=80);} .jssora03udn {background-position: -5px -35px;opacity: .3; filter:alpha(opacity=30); } .jssora03ddn { background-position: -65px -35px;opacity: .3; filter:alpha(opacity=30); }'
    
    arrowstyle = document.createElement('style');
    arrowstyle.type = 'text/css';
    if (arrowstyle.styleSheet){
     arrowstyle.styleSheet.cssText = arrowcss;
    } else {
     arrowstyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arrowcss));
    }
    //_container.appendChild(arrowstyle);
    
    return arrowstyle;
   }
   catch(e)
   {
    alert("Error :: SliderOptions() :: ArrowNavigatorVerticalStyle() :: " + e.Message);
   }
  };
  
  VerticalArrowNavigatorPrevious = function()
  {
   try
   {
    divLeftArrowNav = document.createElement("span");        
    divLeftArrowNav.setAttribute("u","arrowleft");
    divLeftArrowNav.setAttribute("class","jssora03u");
    divLeftArrowNav.setAttribute("style","width: 50px; height: 50px; top: 8px; left: 40%;");
    //_container.appendChild(divLeftArrowNav);
    
    return divLeftArrowNav;
   }
   catch(e)
   {
    alert("Error :: SliderOptions() :: LeftArrowNavigatorVertical() :: " + e.Message);
   }
  };
  
  VerticalArrowNavigatorNext = function()
  { 
   try
   {
    divRightArrowNav = document.createElement("span");        
    divRightArrowNav.setAttribute("u","arrowright");
    divRightArrowNav.setAttribute("class","jssora03d");
    divRightArrowNav.setAttribute("style","width: 50px; height: 50px; bottom: 8px; left: 40%");
    //_container.appendChild(divRightArrowNav); 

    return divRightArrowNav;   
   }
   catch(e)
   {
    alert("Error :: SliderOptions() :: RightArrowNavigatorVertical() :: " + e.Message);
   }
  };
 
 try
 {
  var ImageContainer = [4];
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {   
  ImageContainer[i] = { src : "images/Default/00" + (i+1) + ".jpg" };
  } 
   
  //Removes Existing Child
  while (_container.hasChildNodes())   
   _container.removeChild(_container.firstChild);
   
  //Grid Slider Options
  var gridBulletNavOptions = {$Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$, $ChanceToShow: 2, $AutoCenter: 2, $Steps: 1, $Lanes: 1, $SpacingX: 0,$SpacingY: 0,$Orientation: 2 }
  
  var gridArrowNavOptions = {$Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$, $ChanceToShow: 2, $AutoCenter: 1, $Steps: 1 };
  
  var options = { $AutoPlay: false, $AutoPlaySteps: 1, $AutoPlayInterval: 2000, $FillMode:0, $DisplayPieces: 3, $SlideWidth:900, $SlideHeight:150, $ArrowKeyNavigation: false, $SlideDuration: 1000, $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 30, $SlideSpacing: 3, $ParkingPosition: 0, $PauseOnHover: 3, $PlayOrientation: 2, $DragOrientation: 2, $BulletNavigatorOptions: gridBulletNavOptions, $ArrowNavigatorOptions: gridArrowNavOptions }
  
  //Row Slider Options
  var rowBulletNavOptions = {$Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$, $ChanceToShow: 2, $AutoCenter: 3, $Steps: 1, $Lanes: 1, $SpacingX: 0,$SpacingY: 0,$Orientation: 1 }
  
  var rowArrowNavOptions ={$Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$, $ChanceToShow: 2, $AutoCenter: 2, $Steps: 1 };
  
  var rowOptions = { $AutoPlay: false, $AutoPlaySteps: 1, $AutoPlayInterval: 2000, $FillMode:0, $DisplayPieces: 3, $SlideWidth:300, $SlideHeight:150, $ArrowKeyNavigation: false, $SlideDuration: 1000, $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 30, $SlideSpacing: 3, $ParkingPosition: 0, $PauseOnHover: 3, $PlayOrientation: 1, $DragOrientation: 1, $BulletNavigatorOptions: rowBulletNavOptions, $ArrowNavigatorOptions: rowArrowNavOptions};
  
  var iTop=0;
  
  //Grid Slides creation
  var divGridSlides = document.createElement("div");        
  divGridSlides.setAttribute("u","slides");    
  divGridSlides.setAttribute("style","position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px;width:900px; height:450px;");
  
  //Adding grid slides to Grid slider
  _container.appendChild(divGridSlides); 
  
  //Bullet for Grid slider
  _container.appendChild(GridBulletNavigatorStyle());  
  _container.appendChild(GridBulletNavigator());
  
  //Row Slider creation
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {  
   var rowName = _name + "_row_" + i;
   //Container for Row Slider
   var divRowContainer = document.createElement("div");    
   divRowContainer.setAttribute("style","position:absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: " + iTop +  "px; width:900px; height:150px; ");    
   //Row Slider
   var divRowSliderContainer = document.createElement("div");     
   divRowSliderContainer.setAttribute("id", rowName);
   divRowSliderContainer.setAttribute("style","position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width:900px; height: 150px;");          
   //Removes Existing Child
   while (divRowSliderContainer.hasChildNodes())   
    divRowSliderContainer.removeChild(divRowSliderContainer.firstChild); 
   
   //Row slides creation
   var divRowSlides = document.createElement("div");        
   divRowSlides.setAttribute("u","slides");    
   divRowSlides.setAttribute("style","position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px;width:900px; height:150px;");
   
   //Image creation
   for (var j = 0; j < ImageContainer.length; j++)
   {   
    var divimg = document.createElement("div"); 
    divimg.setAttribute("style","position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width:300px; height:150px; ");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("u","image");
    img.src = ImageContainer[j].src;
    divimg.appendChild(img);
    divRowSlides.appendChild(divimg);
   }  
   
   //Adding row slides to row slider
   divRowSliderContainer.appendChild(divRowSlides);
   
   //Bullet for row slider
   divRowSliderContainer.appendChild(BulletNavigatorStyle());
   divRowSliderContainer.appendChild(BulletNavigator());
   
   //Arrow for row slider
   divRowSliderContainer.appendChild(HorizontalArrowNavigatorStyle());
   divRowSliderContainer.appendChild(HorizontalArrowNavigatorPrevious());
   divRowSliderContainer.appendChild(HorizontalArrowNavigatorNext());
   
   //Adding row slider to row container
   divRowContainer.appendChild(divRowSliderContainer);
   
   //Adding row container to grid's slides node.
   _container.firstChild.appendChild(divRowContainer);
   
   //Row Slider Object creation
   //var jssor_row_slider = new $JssorSlider$(rowName, rowOptions);
   //this.nestedSliderObjects.push(jssor_row_slider);
   
   iTop = iTop + 150;    
  } 

  //Arrow for grid slider
  _container.appendChild(VerticalArrowNavigatorStyle());
  _container.appendChild(VerticalArrowNavigatorPrevious());
  _container.appendChild(VerticalArrowNavigatorNext()); 
  
  //Row Slider Object creation
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
   var rowName = _name + "_row_" + i;
   var jssor_row_slider = new $JssorSlider$(rowName, rowOptions);
   
   function rowsliderOnClick(slideIndex) 
   { 
    try
    { //Sets the row's slide index
     this.currentRowItem = slideIndex;
     this.isSlideClicked=true;    
    }
    catch(e)
    {
     alert("Error :: sliderOnClick() :: " + e.Message);
    }
   }
   jssor_row_slider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_CLICK, rowsliderOnClick);
   this.nestedSliderObjects.push(jssor_row_slider);   
  }   
   
    
  //Grid Slider Creation 
  jssor_grid_slider = new $JssorSlider$(_name, options);

  function sliderOnClick(slideIndex) 
  { 
   try
   { 
    var fn=_name + "_clicked";
    if(this.isSlideClicked==true)
    {
     window[fn].apply(null, [slideIndex, this.currentRowItem]); 
    }
    this.isSlideClicked=false;
    
    
   }
   catch(e)
   {
    alert("Error :: sliderOnClick() :: " + e.Message);
   }
  }
  jssor_grid_slider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_CLICK, sliderOnClick);
  
 } 
 catch(e)
 {
  alert("Error :: CreateGridSlider() :: " + e.Message);
 }

 
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
 <!--
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Release/JQueryLib/jssor.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Release/JQueryLib/jssor.slider.js"></script>-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Release/JQueryLib/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./GridSlider.js"></script>  
    <title>Demo - Grid Slider</title> 
</head>
<body style="font-family:Arial, Verdana;background-color:#fff;">        
 
 <script> 
  var Control1;
  createSlider = function ()
  {
   try
   {   
    
    //Grid
    Control1 = new CreateGridSlider("slider1_container", document.getElementById("slider1_container"));
    
   }
   catch(e)
   {
    alert("Error : createSlider() : " + e.Message);
   }
  }
 </script>
    <!-- Slides Container -->   
 <input type="button" value="Load Slider Control" onclick="createSlider()" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; width: 150px; height: 30px;"/> 
 
 <div id="slider1" width="900px" height="460px" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 10px; width: 900px; height: 460px;background-color:#F8F8FF;">
 <div id="slider1_container" class="carouselSlider" width="900" height="450" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 10px; width: 900px; height: 450px; background-color:#F8F8FF;"></div>
 </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

However, I am facing the following issues:

1.Bullet navigator doesn't come for the grid container slider and the first row slider whereas the same has come for other row sliders.

2.Arrow navigator(Vertical previous & next arrows) has come for the grid container slider but nothing happens on click of arrow.

3.On Click of a image in a row slider, unable to call a row specific method from the rowSliderOnClick handler. It always calls the method bound to last row slider object. The posted code didn't have the implementation for method binding logic.

Comment: Please consider posting the code used to create the JSSOR grid slide. I have edited the formating but you must add the code right below the first line.

Comment: Please post the code (javascript+html) that you created dynamically.

Comment: @jssor: I have posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please set `$UISearchMode` to 0 for the main slider.

If `$UISearchMode` is 1, the main slider will search (recursively deep search) for the first bullet/arrow navigator within the scope of its container, the bullet/arrow navigator of the first child will be reinitialized as the bullet/arrow navigator of the main slider.

If `$UISearchMode` is 0, it will search (no deep search) for child elements at the first level.

So, please replace

```
var options = { $AutoPlay: false, $AutoPlaySteps: 1, $AutoPlayInterval: 2000, $FillMode: 0, $Cols: 3, $SlideWidth: 900, $SlideHeight: 150, $ArrowKeyNavigation: false, $SlideDuration: 1000, $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 30, $SlideSpacing: 3, $Align: 0, $PauseOnHover: 3, $PlayOrientation: 2, $DragOrientation: 2, $BulletNavigatorOptions: gridBulletNavOptions, $ArrowNavigatorOptions: gridArrowNavOptions }
```

with

```
var options = { $UISearchMode: 0, $AutoPlay: false, $AutoPlaySteps: 1, $AutoPlayInterval: 2000, $FillMode: 0, $Cols: 3, $SlideWidth: 900, $SlideHeight: 150, $ArrowKeyNavigation: false, $SlideDuration: 1000, $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 30, $SlideSpacing: 3, $Align: 0, $PauseOnHover: 3, $PlayOrientation: 2, $DragOrientation: 2, $BulletNavigatorOptions: gridBulletNavOptions, $ArrowNavigatorOptions: gridArrowNavOptions }
```

Comment: Awesome, it works. Thank you for your response. Any clue on issue #3?.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, you don't need multi copies of `jssorb03` and `jssora03` css.

You can move it to `<head>` element, and you need only one copy,

```
<html>
<head>
...
    <style type="text/css">
        .jssorb03 div, .jssorb03 div:hover, .jssorb03 .av {
            background: url(../img/b05.png) no-repeat;
            overflow: hidden;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .jssorb03 div {
            background-position: -5px -4px;
        }

            .jssorb03 div:hover, .jssorb03 .av:hover {
                background-position: -35px -4px;
            }

        .jssorb03 .av {
            background-position: -65px -4px;
        }

        .jssorb03 .dn, .jssorb03 .dn:hover {
            background-position: -95px -4px;
        }
    </style>

    <style type="text/css">
        .jssora03l, .jssora03r, .jssora03ldn, .jssora03rdn {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            background: url(../img/a03.png) no-repeat;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .jssora03l {
            background-position: -3px -33px;
        }

        .jssora03r {
            background-position: -63px -33px;
        }

        .jssora03l:hover {
            background-position: -123px -33px;
        }

        .jssora03r:hover {
            background-position: -183px -33px;
        }

        .jssora03ldn {
            background-position: -243px -33px;
        }

        .jssora03rdn {
            background-position: -303px -33px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
...
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Re: #3

Everything is OK but the `i` changed in the loop, the `i` is always 4 then.

You can create a proxy function to hold the `i` as a parameter.

```
//Row Slider Object creation
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    var rowName = _name + "_row_" + i;
    var jssor_row_slider = new $JssorSlider$(rowName, rowOptions);

    function rowsliderOnClick(rowIndex, slideIndex) {
        try {   //Sets the row's slide index
            this.currentRowItem = slideIndex;
            this.isSlideClicked = true;

            alert("row: " + rowIndex + " col: " + slideIndex);
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert("Error :: sliderOnClick() :: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
    jssor_row_slider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_CLICK, $Jssor$.$CreateCallback(null, rowsliderOnClick, i));
    this.nestedSliderObjects.push(jssor_row_slider);
}
```

Note that, in jssor library, you can use `$Jssor$.$CreateCallback` to create a proxy function. This api is available only in `jssor.slider.min.js` instead of `jssor.slider.mini.js`.

And the equivalent api in jquery is `$.proxy`.

Comment: Thank you, It works fine. I have used bind() to bind the call back method with i as parameter.

Comment: `function rowsliderOnClickProxy (index, slideIndex)
{
try
 {
  var func = _name + "_row_" + index + "_clicked";    
  window[func].apply(null, [slideIndex]);    
 }
 catch(e)
 {
  alert("Error :: rowsliderOnClickProxy () :: " + e.Message);
 }
}
jssor_row_slider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_CLICK, rowsliderOnClickProxy.bind(null, i));`

Comment: Please note browser compatibility. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind